# JavaFx. TreeView. Как правильно создать?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

Есть класс:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClientIO extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
primaryStage.setTitle("client");
primaryStage.setMinHeight(600);
primaryStage.setMinWidth(620);
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 620, 600));
primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}
}

Также есть класс, в котором описано весь GUI приложения:

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class GUI {
@FXML
private Button connect;
...
@FXML
private TreeView<String> localtree;

public void serverConnect(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
TreeItem<String> rootItem = null;
    if (dir != null) {
        localpath.setText(dir.getAbsolutePath());
        rootItem = new TreeItem<> (dir.getAbsolutePath());
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<> ("Message" + i);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }
    }
    localtree = new TreeView<> (rootItem);
 }
```

Ну собственно проблема с отрисовкой TreeView. Он не отрисовывается. Вроде как нужно опять указать Stage. Подскажите каким образом это поправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у вас в последней строчке в методу serverConnect:

```
localtree = new TreeView<> (rootItem);
```

У вас localtree уже существует ( помечен аннотацией @FXML) и пересоздавать его не надо.

Если вам необоходимо просетать рутовый айтем, то делать надо так:

```
localtree.setRoot(rootItem);
```

Comment: да все так, проблема решена